# how to handle two processes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code only handles the script which contain **setInterval** and the other script is unreachable.

What should I do to handle both scripts?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Top News</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.5.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="top-new-content">
        <div class="one" style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px; background:yellow;width:300px;height:100px; border: 1px #979797 solid">
            <img src="image/news/img.jpg" width="100px" height="50px" />
        </div>
        <div class="two" style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px;background:yellow;width:300px;height:100px; border: 1px #979797 solid">
            two two two two two two two ...
        </div>
        <div class="three" style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 10px; background:yellow;width:300px;height:100px; border: 1px #979797 solid">
            three three three three three ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="top-news-category" style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 111px; border: 1px #979797 solid; border-top: none; background-color: yellow">
        &nbsp;<span id="a">One |</span>
        <span id="b">Two |</span>
        <span id="c">Three</span>&nbsp;
    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval(function() {
            $('div.one').fadeIn(1000);
            $('div.two').fadeOut(1000);
            $('div.three').fadeOut(1000);
            $("*").delay(3000);
            $('div.two').fadeIn(1000);
            $('div.one').fadeOut(1000);
            $('div.three').fadeOut(1000);
            $("*").delay(3000);
            $('div.three').fadeIn(1000);
            $('div.one').fadeOut(1000);
            $('div.two').fadeOut(1000);
            $("*").delay(3000);
        }, 0);
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".top-news-category #a").click(function(){
            $("div.one").fadeIn("slow", "linear");
            $("div.two").fadeOut("slow", "linear");
            $("div.three").fadeOut("slow", "linear");
        });
        $(".top-news-category #b").click(function(){
            alert("TWO");
            $("div.one").fadeOut("slow", "linear");
            $("div.three").fadeOut("slow", "linear");
            $("div.two").fadeIn("slow", "linear");
        });
        $(".top-news-category #c").click(function(){
            $("div.one").fadeOut("slow", "linear");
            $("div.three").fadeOut("slow", "linear");
            $("div.three").fadeIn("slow", "linear");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: just copy your first script inside jquery ready function. it will work

Comment: i wrap the script with  $(document).ready(  but its Still the same

Comment: can you show the modified code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi ammar i have edited by answer check it..

```
setInterval(function() {
    $('div.one').fadeIn(1500);
    $('div.two').fadeOut(1500);
    $('div.three').fadeOut(1500);
    $("*").delay(15000);
    $('div.two').fadeIn(1500);
    $('div.one').fadeOut(1500);
    $('div.three').fadeOut(1500);
    $("*").delay(15000);
    $('div.three').fadeIn(1500);
    $('div.one').fadeOut(1500);
    $('div.two').fadeOut(1500);
    $("*").delay(15000);
}, 100000);
```

When you study the setInterval method description the first parameter is function and second parameter is the duration in milliseconds after which the function needs to be executed again and again. Earlier you have specified it as 0 which caused the problem.  Hope this will help you,....

Comment: that not what i need, you can't select the category by selecting it. only the setInterval works properly

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not running your first snippet on document.ready. Try wrapping it around `$(document).ready(...` and it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The script tags need to be inside before the closing  tag. Also I would recommend wrapping the both script tags with the 'document ready'.

Cleanest/shortest way of using document ready in JQuery.

```
$(function() {
    ...my code here...
});
```